# jquery comparing value in if statement

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using `javascript` in `jsp` to hide and show some labels. I'm using `ajax` to retrieve data from database and comparing it with a string. 
In the below code I'm passing "1" as the parameter which is `pass` but it always goes to the else part. Am I doing something wrong?
I even tried with `null` but it also doesn't hit.

Here's my code actually:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pass; //pass = 1
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ValidateUser',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      var post = data;
      $("#username").append('<p>' + post + '</p>');

      pass = data;
    }

  });

  setAttributes(pass);
});

function setAttributes(pass) {
  if (pass === "1") {
    document.getElementById("ulUsername").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("ulCreateAccount").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ulUsername").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("ulCreateAccount").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is dataType of pass? number or string?

Comment: You're calling `setAttributes` before the AJAX call completes. Call it in the `success` function.

Comment: data type is string

Comment: i think comparison happens with string 1 and integer 1,(1==="1"), make if (pass===1)

Comment: @NagaSaiA The comparison is happening before the variable is set, because it's being assigned in an asynchronous function.

Comment: @Barmar can you please give me an example.

Comment: @jayz Move the call to `setAttributes` to the line after `pass = data`.

Comment: Did you try reading the question I linked to? It explains the problem and solution in great detail.

Comment: Thank you all. It works fine with the change @Barmar suggested. I will read it.